# Link two Google Sheets programmatically using Google Sheets\Google Drive .NET Api

Tags: c#, .net, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I have two google sheets that are created by api, one of them uses 'IMPORTRANGE' function to get data from another sheet, but it requires to click the "ALLOW" button of an import range to connect two spreadsheets. Is there a way to connect them programmatically using Google Sheets\Google Drive .NET API?

[image]

I've searched through API reference, but no luck to find answer I need

Comment: you could use a service account and grant it access to the sheet you can do this programmatically with .net

Comment: @linda-lawton-daimto could you please provide some links so i could look into it?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q5b0ivBYqeQ  this will get you access to drive with a service account.   I need to look around i should have a sheets sample for .net some where.